# Moving Window Calculation Across Multiple Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have several two-dimensional data arrays loaded into NumPy arrays, all of which have identical dimensions. These shared dimensions are 2606x and 1228y.

I am interested in computing calculations between the first two arrays (a1 & a2) across a moving window, using a window sized 2x by 2y, with the resultant calculation then applied to the third array. Specifically, the workflow would be:

1. Finding the the maximum & minimum value of a1 at the piece of this moving window
2. Selecting the corresponding array indices of these values
3. Extracting the values at these indices of a2
4. Cast the calculation result to each of the indices in the third array (a3) inside the moving window.

I know that this process involves the following pieces of code to obtain the values I require:

```
idx1 = np.where(a1 == a1.max())
idx2 = np.where(a1 == a1.min())
val1 = a2[idx1[1], idx1[2]]
val2 = a2[idx2[1], idx2[2]]
```

What additional code is required to perform this moving window along the identically sized arrays?

Comment: I don't understand Step 4. Do you mean that you want to copy those values of a2 to a3?

Comment: @RoySmart correct!

Comment: This is a little sticky since the max value for one window could be the min value for another window, which means the final answer depends on how you slide the window across the input. Is this what you expect?

Comment: @RoySmart is it possible to have the moving window cover only a new section with each move, if that make sense? So for example [0x-4x,0y-4y] then [5x-9x,0y-4y], etc., in that fashion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array shape is divisible by your window size, you can use `numpy.reshape` to split your array up into little windows such that your original array shape of `(2606, 1228)` becomes `(2606/2, 2, 1228/2, 2)`.

If `numpy.argmin` accepted sequences of axes, this would be easier, but since it only accepts a single axis (or `None` but we don't want that), we need to compress the two window axes into a single axes. To do that, we use `numpy.moveaxis` to make the shape `(2606/2, 1228/2, 2, 2)` and then `numpy.reshape` again to flatten the last two axes into `(2606/2, 1228/2, 4)`.

With that headache over with, we can then use `numpy.argmin` and `numpy.argmax` on the last axis to compute the indices you're interested in and use advanced indexing to write the corresponding value of `a2` to `a3`. After that, we just have to undo the `reshape` and `moveaxis` operations that were done to `a3`.

```py
import numpy as np

shape = (4, 6)
a1 = np.random.random(shape)
a2 = np.random.random(shape)
a3 = np.zeros(shape)

win_x = 2
win_y = 2

shape_new = (shape[0] // win_x, win_x, shape[1] // win_y, win_y)

a1_r = np.moveaxis(a1.reshape(shape_new), 1, 2).reshape(*shape_new[::2], -1)
a2_r = np.moveaxis(a2.reshape(shape_new), 1, 2).reshape(*shape_new[::2], -1)
a3_r = np.moveaxis(a3.reshape(shape_new), 1, 2).reshape(*shape_new[::2], -1)

index_x, index_y = np.indices(shape_new[::2])
index_min = np.argmin(a1_r, axis=-1)
index_max = np.argmax(a1_r, axis=-1)

a3_r[index_x, index_y, index_min] = a2_r[index_x, index_y, index_min]
a3_r[index_x, index_y, index_max] = a2_r[index_x, index_y, index_max]

a3 = np.moveaxis(a3_r.reshape(*shape_new[::2], win_x, win_y), 2, 1).reshape(shape)

print(a1)
print()
print(a2)
print()
print(a3)
```

Outputs

```
[[0.54885307 0.74457945 0.84943538 0.14139329 0.68678556 0.03460323]
 [0.74031057 0.5499962  0.03148748 0.13936734 0.05006111 0.88850868]
 [0.97789608 0.13262023 0.76350358 0.74640822 0.7918286  0.80675845]
 [0.35784598 0.20918229 0.82880072 0.06051794 0.0825886  0.6398353 ]]

[[0.66176657 0.10120202 0.15306892 0.05963046 0.79057051 0.08837686]
 [0.78550049 0.09918834 0.00213652 0.61053454 0.42966757 0.25952916]
 [0.00387273 0.78247644 0.65549303 0.39351233 0.11002493 0.55652453]
 [0.06047582 0.87997514 0.60820023 0.06705212 0.34581512 0.93504438]]

[[0.66176657 0.10120202 0.15306892 0.         0.         0.08837686]
 [0.         0.         0.00213652 0.         0.         0.25952916]
 [0.00387273 0.78247644 0.         0.         0.         0.55652453]
 [0.         0.         0.60820023 0.06705212 0.34581512 0.        ]]
```

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt solution, this is exactly what I'm looking to accomplish! I'm accepting this answer now, is there any reason why argmax/argmin doesn't accept sequences of axes to begin with?

Comment: I think it's because it would change the signature of `argmax`. If there's more than one axis, the return type of would have to be a tuple of arrays instead of just a single array of indices.

Comment: One additional question: if I decided to generate a fourth array where I did some sort of calculation with the max & min and wanted to cast the result of this operation (For example, 4.5398) identically to all parts of the array in the moving window (2x by 2y) in this case, is that possible or would I need to alter your solution some?

Comment: Should be pretty easy, you could just do `a4_r[:] = new_val[..., np.newaxis]` assuming that `new_val` has shape `(2606/2, 1228/2)`. Or even faster is just to broadcast: `a4_r = np.broadcast_to(new_val[..., np.newaxis], a3_r.shape)`